# App Store: may my app be rejected if I use different device sizes than expected for video previews?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have developed a game app that I am done developing, now I am working on the screenshots and video preview for the App Store.

My problem is that I tried recording the app preview using the simulator to get both 5.5" and 6.5" display sizes, but the records end up being too laggy and unusable.
So I thought of using my physical device instead (an iPhone XR), but I was wondering that if I use a video editor to embed the record from my iPhone XR in a video that would be sized 2688x1242 for 6.5" display and 2208x1242 for 5.5" display *(see below)*, would my app be rejected because the visual doesn't match the device display size?

*(visual example)*
[image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

First off, Apple may reject if you use the simulator. They will kindly ask you to use the physical device instead to show your app in use.
My recommendation would be finding two iPhones with 5.5" and 6.5" display sizes and screen recording your app.
You can of course try your way and let us all know if that has worked or not. But if Apple rejects, don't worry, they'll send you an email with explanations/further instructions and most likely will ask you to just replace your videos (without submitting a binary once again).